# How rate limiting will work when same instance group is behind two different load balancers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, autoscaling, rate-limiting

I was reading about rate limiting and auto-scaling in GCP and got stuck at this question:

Scenario:

1. I created a instance group `ig` with auto-scaling `OFF`.
2. I created a load balancer `lb1`, details are:

   - `lb1` contains a backend service `bs1` which points to instance group
     `ig` and Maximum RPS set to 1000 for `whole group`.
   - frontend port :8080
   - path rule : /alpha/*
   - `lb1` is an external load balancer
3. I created one more load balancer `lb2`, details are:

   - `lb2` contains a backend service `bs2` which points to instance group
     `ig` and Maximum RPS set to 2000 for `whole group`.
   - frontend port :9090
   - path rule : /beta/*
   - `lb2` is an regional load balancer

Question that I have:

- Who will monitor the requests served by the both the load balancers?
- Which limit will be honoured 1000 or 2000?
- Will the overall requests (i.e via `lb1` and `lb2`) will be rate limited or individual limits will be applied for both the request flows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR - [The RPS is set in the `Backend Service`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/backendServices), so each load balancer will have its own `RPS` limit independent of another.

- > Who will monitor the requests served by the both the load balancers?

Google Compute Engine (GCE) will monitor the requests being served by the load balancers and direct traffic accordingly to stay within the RPS limit of each backend within the backend service.

- > Which limit will be honoured 1000 or 2000?

1000 with respect to the first load balancer and 2000 with respect to the second load balancer. Remember that the you're using 2 separate backend services `bs1` and `bs2` for `lb1` and `lb2` respectively.

- > Will the overall requests (i.e via lb1 and lb2) will be rate limited or individual limits will be applied for both the request flows?

Requests going through `lb1` for `bs1` will conform to maximum of `1000 RPS` per backend VM. Requests going through `lb2` for `bs2` will conform to maximum of `2000 RPS` per backend VM. So your service running in any given backend VM instance, should be capable of handling at least `3000 RPS`.

## Longer version

Instance groups do not have a way to specify RPS, [only backend services do](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#backend_service_components). Instance groups only help to group a list of instances. So although you could use the same instance groups in multiple backend services, you need to account for the `RPS` value you set in the corresponding backend service if your goal is to share instances among multiple backend services. GCE will not be able to figure this out automatically.

A backend service represents a micro-service ideally, which is served by a group of backend VMs (from the instance group). You should calculate beforehand how much maximum RPS a single backend instance  (i.e. your service running inside the VM) can handle to set this limit. If you intend to share VMs across backend services, you will need to ensure that the combined `RPS` limit in the worst case is something that your service inside the VM is able to handle.

Google Compute Engine (GCE) will monitor the metrics per backend service (i.e. number of requests per second in your case) and will use that for load balancing. Each load balancer is logically different, and hence there will be no aggregation across load balancers (even if using the same instance group).

> [**Load distribution algorithm**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#load_distribution_algorithm)
>
> HTTP(S) load balancing provides two methods of determining instance
>   load. Within the backend service object, the balancingMode property
>   selects between the requests per second (RPS) and CPU utilization
>   modes. Both modes allow a maximum value to be specified; **the HTTP load
>   balancer will try to ensure that load remains under the limit, but
>   short bursts above the limit can occur during failover or load spike
>   events**.
>
> Incoming requests are sent to the region closest to the user, provided
>   that region has available capacity. If more than one zone is
>   configured with backends in a region, the traffic is distributed
>   across the instance groups in each zone according to each group's
>   capacity. Within the zone, the requests are spread evenly over the
>   instances using a round-robin algorithm. Round-robin distribution can
>   be overridden by configuring session affinity.

## maxRate and maxRatePerInstance

In the backend service, there are [2 configuration fields related to RPS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/backendServices#resource-representations), one is `maxRate` and other is `maxRatePerInstance`. `maxRate` can be used to set the `RPS` per group whereas `maxRatePerInstance` can be used to set the `RPS` per instance. It looks like both can be used in conjunction if needed.

> **backends[].maxRate**
>
> integer
>
> The **max requests per second (RPS) of the
>   group**. Can be used with either `RATE` or `UTILIZATION` balancing modes,
>   but required if `RATE` mode. For `RATE` mode, either `maxRate` or
>   `maxRatePerInstance` must be set.
>
> This cannot be used for internal load balancing.
>
> **backends[].maxRatePerInstance**
>
> float
>
> The **max requests per second (RPS)
>   that a single backend instance can handle**.This is used to calculate
>   the capacity of the group. Can be used in either balancing mode. For
>   RATE mode, either maxRate or maxRatePerInstance must be set.
>
> This cannot be used for internal load balancing.

## Receiving requests at a higher rate than specified RPS

If you happen to receive requests at a rate higher than the RPS and you have autoscaling disabled, I could not find any documentation on the Google Cloud website regarding the exact expected behavior. The closest I could find is [this one](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps#requests_per_second_rps), where it specifies that the load balancer will try to keep each instance at or below the specified `RPS`. So it could mean that the requests could get dropped if it exceeds the `RPS`, and clients might see one of the `5XX` error codes (possibly [`502`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#what_is_logged)) based on this:

> **failed_to_pick_backend**
>
> The load balancer failed to pick a healthy backend to handle the
>   request.
>
> **502**

You could probably figure it out the hard way by setting a fairly low `RPS` like `10` or `20` and see what happens. Look at the timestamps at which you receive the requests on your backend to determine the behavior. Also, the limiting might not happen on exactly the 11th or 21st request, so try sending far more than that per second to verify if the requests are being dropped.

## [With Autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cpu-load-balancing#scaling_based_on_https_load_balancing_serving_capacity)

If you enable autoscaling though, this will automatically trigger the autoscaler and make it expand the number of instances in the instance group based on the target utilization level you set in the Autoscaler.

**NOTE:** Updated answer since you actually specified that you're using 2 separate backend services.

Comment: What will happen in case if say `lb1` for `bs1` is serving 1000 RPS already and I it received a new requests (i.e 1001 request). Will it be dropped or queued??

Comment: @VikasVerma - Updated answer to describe the behavior. There is no solid documentation on the site regarding this but it looks like it will just be dropped if you exceed the RPS and you do not have autoscaling.

Comment: I just had the same question and the Google Cloud support answered that requests will be queued. It's still not documented and I do not have any further details like how large the queue is and how it behaves if you are going to exceed the queue's limit size (rejecting new requests or does it drop items from the queue?).